# Query by date from custom field

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I would like to get WordPress posts whose custom field date is in the future, but I have a problem getting correct results from this query:

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_type'      => 'matches',
    'meta_key'       => 'date',
    'compare'        => '>=',
    'meta_value'     => '2016-11-12',
    'type'           => 'DATE'
);
```

All I get are posts where the date matches '2016-11-12', though I use **'compare' => '>=',** and even **'compare' => '>',** shows these very same results. I don't understand that at all!

Comment: There is no argument named `compare` outside of a `meta_query`, it is `meta_compare.`

Comment: @Milo as an answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an argument [meta_compare](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). Use it for comparison.

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_type'      => 'matches',
    'meta_key'       => 'date',
    'meta_compare'   => '>',
    'meta_value'     => '2016-11-12',
    'type'           => 'DATE'
);
```